# How to add global config using service account in GitHub

Tags: git, cmd, git-bash

Git bash is installed in server01, and I have a script for automation(E:\Apps\Script\ExportGit.cmd). Running the script using the service account (via web service) gave me error 128.

Example of git commands inside the script:
 `git ls-remote https://"token"@website.local/OrgName/RepoName`

I googled and found out that I need to add git config global user.name and user.email.

After adding and executing the `git config --global --list` or `git config --list`, the user.name and user.email is not yet added to the config.

**Note:** The server01 is using Windows OS. Remote using my account has no problems using git commands. Also it's forbidden for us to use the service account to remote access the server.

Comment: Do you really have doublequotes in your URL?

Comment: Nope. I can't write <token> so i just used "token"

Comment: I don't understand! Why can you not write `<token>`, and are you sure that you really have greater than and less than characters in your URL? It is not possible for us to diagnose an issue, if you cannot show us a representative example we can use to reproduce it.